# Group by Row/Column Issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a series of counts of rows based upon a GROUP BY for a column. What I've got at the moment is this:

```
select grouping_column,
(select count(value) from table where value IS NOT NULL and value BETWEEN 0 AND 300) AS Count_A,
(select count(value) from table where value IS NOT NULL and value BETWEEN 301 AND 600) AS Count_B,
...many more like this...
from table
group by grouping_column;
```

What I imagined I would get would be something like:

Grouping_column | Count_A | Count_B

With Count_A and Count_B split by each level of grouping_column. However, this doesn't happen. Instead, what I get is the levels of the grouping_column listed, along with a count of ALL values that fall within the range specified by Count_A and Count_B.

I've tried a number of different versions of this, but seem to be off the mark each time. What is it I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    grouping_column,
    SUM(value BETWEEN 0 AND 300) AS Count_A,
    SUM(value BETWEEN 301 AND 600) AS Count_B,
    ...many more like this...
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY grouping_column
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great - it's working now! One question though. In the query you have suggested, you've used SUM - how come this seems to be doing the job of counting the number of selected cells? I changed SUM to COUNT and it simply counted everything grouped by grouping_column.